# Activiti Diagram Viewer, Get diagram layout failure: parsererror

Tags: json, jsonp, activiti, parse-error

I tried to integrate the diagram viewer in my webapp. The error happend while loading the page http://localhost:8080/MyActiviti/diagram-viewer/index.html?processDefinitionId=myProcess:1:4&processInstanceId=10001

The following is error info, I haved checked the json format of responseText, any other solutions?
[image]

Comment: Did you check the server logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Just comment dataType line in ActivitiRest.js.There should be three positions.
like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        //dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(data, textStatus) {
            var processDefinition = data;
            if (!processDefinition) {
                console.error("Process definition '" + processDefinitionKey + "' not found");
            } else {
              callback.apply({processDefinitionId: processDefinition.id});
            }
        }
    }).done
```